# Convergence of series $\sum_n n^p \log(1+\frac{1}{n^2 +2n})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I suspect the following series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^p \log(1+\frac{1}{n^2 +2n})$

is convergent for $0<p <1$ and divergent for $p \geq 1$. Is that right? If so, how do I prove this. What test can I use? The ratio and root one don't seem to help...

Comment: By equivalence, it is immediate.

Comment: Please explain further. Equivalence to what? What do you mean by equivalence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : $\log(1+x)=x+o(x)$ as $x\to0$
Use this and try to compare it to series of form $n^p$, to find out where it converges.

Comment: I see...so it is true then.